# C++ Armadillo eigenvalues for large sym matrix

Tags: c++, eigen, armadillo

In my program I use armadillo to repeatedly perform eigenvalue computations on a large dense real symmetric matrix. The corresponding function should be

```
arma::mat H = ...; //dense, real, symmetric >= 300x300
arma::eig_sym(H);
```

which has to be done some 100.000 times, therefore I was wondering whethter there are faster ways to do this. I also have to get *all* of the eigenvalues. I already tried the Eigen and Spectra libraries which turned out to be slower, and I tried using ARPACK-Armadillo, but ran into trouble with conflicting definitions in different header files and gave up. I also linked blas and lapack, since armadillo is supposed to be using those if I understood that correctly.

Comment: Since you need all the eigenvalues, then `arma::eig_sym()` is hard to improve in terms of speed.